# Pela experiências dos atuais, qual é o tempo de moderação ideal para SOpt?

Tags: debate, eleição

Com base na experiência dos moderadores atuais, qual é o tempo de moderação ideal para se dedicar a atividade no SOpt?

Answer (score 16):

Eu venho dedicando um tempo insano ao site desde que fui apontado moderador temporário, então não sou parâmetro. Acho que tenho alguns parafusos a menos.

Mas acho o seguinte: quem quiser ser moderador precisa estar ligado no que está acontecendo no site o máximo de tempo possível, mesmo que o tempo gasto intervindo não seja tão grande. Isso é tanto uma demonstração de envolvimento com o site (o que é desejável num moderador), quanto uma oportunidade de acompanhar as coisas acontecendo em tempo real. Claro que não é necessário intervir em tempo real – na verdade, eu geralmente procuro esperar para ter um certo distanciamento crítico –, mas ver as coisas acontecendo ajuda você a "sacar" o site. Tentar refazer a cronologia, olhando timestamps, é tedioso, e não tem o mesmo efeito.

Acho que não respondi à pergunta, mas espero ter contribuído para o debate.

Comment: Confirmo oficialmente que o @bfavaretto tem, de fato, parafusos a menos

Answer (score 10):

O tempo varia segundo dois critérios, principalmente:

## Movimentação do site

Para acompanhar a movimentação diária, estimo que com 1 hora é possível no mínimo acompanhar as novas perguntas e as *flags*. Esse tempo irá aumentando na medida em que a média de perguntas cresce.

Particularmente, não consigo acessar o site fins de semana, então na segunda dá uma sobrecarregada.

Quanto às *flags*, somente em alguns casos é necessário alguma discussão. Na maioria dos casos os moderadores podem dividir o trabalho e, com boa vontade, limpam a fila rapidamente.

## Participação do moderador

Isso é que consome mais tempo e também que varia mais. Quanto mais o moderador participar editando questões, orientando e até respondendo questões, mais tempo terá que passar no site.

Quando fui indicado moderador, acabei por dedicar menos tempo a responder, mais tempo a orientar e mais atenção para tentar salvar questões que seriam fechadas ou removidas.

Também há o tempo no chat, que pode ser de interação com os outros moderadores e a equipe do SE, incluindo o Gabe, ou com os usuários em geral.

## Minha participação

Houve dias em que gastei 4 ou 5 horas no site. Outros dias, nenhum. Na média, estimo que dedico de 1 a 2 horas.

Especialmente nos últimos meses dei uma diminuída na quantidade de interação com o site devido a dois fatores: projeto intenso na empresa, mudança de país.

Não chego perto da participação do @bfavaretto, então talvez dê para me considerar um exemplo mais *moderado* de *moderador*.

Comment: Gostei muito da tua resposta com todos esses pormenores.

Comment: Que trocadilho infame no final do post...